# Minimal image to run hadoop command to an existing Hadoop cluster

Tags: docker, hadoop

I want to run hadoop command to an existing Hadoop cluster via Docker image.

For example:

> hadoop dfs -ls hdfs://192.168.10.1:1234/

Is there any minimal image to run the command? (eg. just use namenode image?)

Comment: What have you found so far? (Type Hadoop /namenode into docker hub) What issues are you having doing so? Or, why do you need Docker instead of just downloading Hadoop CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do the job, with the right config files

https://hub.docker.com/r/ryneyang/hadoop-client

However, it's better just to look at it as a reference and make your own accordingly as this may be absolute.

https://github.com/linehrr/hadoop-client-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

Pretty much what you need to do is install Hadoop binaries and setup configuration files (core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml)

You can also look at WebHDFS and httpFS as potential options to interact with namenode outside of it